# Extract files from a particular date to process the data -- U-SQL

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory, u-sql, azure-stream-analytics

I have two pipelines which will make two files in different paths.  In path 1 i have only 1 file which will have all data. In path 2 i have one file for each day.
Suppose path 1 file is not refreshed for last 2 days and path 2 have files for that last 2 days. Then i want to process that last 2 days in u-sql script. How can we do that ?

Comment: You can input both files, and compare the dates between the two files and then just select the needed files to process them.

Comment: Can you share me sample ?

Comment: add some sample data to your question so I can work with it.